# Get parameters from uri nginx

Tags: nginx

I have a url like this http://example.com/12345

and I would like to put 1234 in a variable in nginx.

I tried this :

```
location /([0-9]+) {
    set my_var = $1;
}
```

But it's not working. Anyone can help ?

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect - see [the manual page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#set).

Comment: I tried with this location`location ~ ^/([0-9]+) {set $myvar $1;}` but it still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Nginx rental variable is not a parameter. So I can not get it